# Have column total appear at end of column. Column changes size

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet that pulls data from another excel. The columns length changes depending on the data it pulls. How do I set a TOTAL to appear at the bottom regardless of how long the column is.

i.e. First run the sheet ends at A10 so the total should appear at A11. Next run it ends at A50 so the TOTAL should appear in A51

The best I could do was add a TOTAL at around A500 and then just delete the blanks above. Yes my data can reach that long.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please can you edit your question to show us what code you have tried so far?

Comment: Why not have the total at the top instead? It's easily accessible and only pushes your data down by one row. Can be just below the header. Would save you a massive headache.

Comment: If you format your range as a table, excel can handle this automatically. Or, you can use VBA, or many other methods really..